# insert and represent intra-document one to many relationship in xml

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq

I have xml data as like following :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classes>
    <class room_id='1'>
        <classArea></classArea>
        <classFloor></classFloor>
        <maxStudents></maxStudents>
        <teachers>
            <teacher_name></teacher_name>
            <teacher_name></teacher_name>
            <teacher_name></teacher_name>
        </teachers>
    </class>
</classes>
```

in asp.net c# web app page I have created textboxes for room_id, classArea, classFloor, maxStudents to allow user to enter a new class, then I created XElement from it to represent xml data as following:

```
XElement class = new XElement("class",
                new XAttribute("room_id", IdTb.Text),
                new XElement ("classArea"...
                ...
                ... maxStudents));
```

adding text box for teacher_name force user to enter only one teacher per class.

my problem is how to allow user to enter multiple values for teacher_name element in teachers element at the same time? because we have multiple values for it, and I do not know how many teacher could be entered one...ten...or more.
what should I use to solve this problem, and to build XElement "class" object with full structure at one shot like press save button?
please lead me to solve it.

Comment: Added sample output code.

Comment: the required output is like above xml snippet. However the output is ok but with only one child <teachers><teacher_name></teacher_name></teachers> , I need a way to input it multiple times beside to other fields. how can i achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing it one [XElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302741.aspx) with teacher name, you're passing it array of XElements.

One of [XElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302741.aspx) overloaded methods is

> public XElement(XName name, params object[] content)

Which will chain all the objects in that array into the same element level.

**Code:**

```
// Just populating the teachers names
var teachers = new List<string> { "Sarah", "Rivka", "Lea", "Rachel" };

// You can change the following line to whatever line you want that produces array of XElement in that format.
var teachersXElements = teachers.Select(teacher => new XElement("teacher_name", teacher));

var myClass = new XElement("class",
        new XAttribute("room_id", 1),
        new XElement ("classArea",
            new XElement("teachers", teachersXElements) // Here the "Magic" happens; simple as that.
        )
);

Console.WriteLine(myClass.ToString());
```

**Sample Output:**

```
<class room_id="1">
  <classArea>
    <teachers>
      <teacher_name>Sarah</teacher_name>
      <teacher_name>Rivka</teacher_name>
      <teacher_name>Lea</teacher_name>
      <teacher_name>Rachel</teacher_name>
    </teachers>
  </classArea>
</class>
```

Comment: thank you fro your answer, my problem is how to make use able to enter multiple values for teacher_names at the same time with other fields, for example a user need to input new class info room_id='1' class_floor='1' max_students='16' all these info are fields on page, now how to make him able to enter "Sarah", "Rivka", "Lea", "Rachel" at the same time? should I put 4 textboxes for teacher names? this is my question, i do not want to add textboxes because I do not know how many teachers to input, so what are alternative solutions?

Comment: Yes, you can make 1 text box and ask the user enter values delimited by some char, let's say ';' which means "Sarah;Rivka;Lea;Rachel" you will split them into array by using `teachers = teachersNames.Split(new [] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)` with this array you can now use the `teachersXElements` assignment row to produce those into XML Elements.

Comment: your answer with your last comment is the need answer, thanks.